# Option menu of the previous fragment is preserved after switching fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, options-menu

I have an activity with a navigation drawer and fragments (Fragment **Lvl 1**). One of these fragments contains nested children(Fragment **Lvl 2**) with a viewpager adapter. When I add an option menu to the nested child (Lvl 2) it **stills appearing** on the newely displayed fragment when I'm switching between fragement (Lvl 1) from the navigation drawer.

It's seems like the Fragment wich containing the view pager is not telling the activity that is has been hidden or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue because I was providing `getFragmentManager()` to `FragmentPagerAdapter` constructor instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved that by calling `Menu.clear()` on `onDetach()` in the nested fragment (Lvl2).

But it will be nice , if someone could provide me a better solution.

Comment: I have the exactly same situation like yours. However, my solution is manually calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in the `onNavigationItemSelected()` of main activity after switching between level 1 fragments.